# c++ it does not switch to case(2)

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int c=0, sum = 0, y;
    cout << "press (1) to find the sum of 2 even numbers between 2 integers or press (2) to find all the prime numbers between 10 and 30,or press -1 to terminate";
    cin >> c;
    while (c != -1)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case (1) :
        {int x=0;
            cout << "enter 2 integers\n";
            cin >> x >> y;
            while (x<= y)
            {
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    sum = sum +x;
                x++;
            }
            cout << "sum is" << sum;
            break;
        }
        case(2) :
        {int counter = 30, counter2 = 1, nod = 0;
            while (counter >= 10)
            {
                while (counter2 >= counter)
                {
                    if (counter%counter2 == 0)
                        nod = nod + 1;
                    counter2++;
                }
                if (nod == 2)
                    cout << counter << " is prime number";
                counter--;
            }
            break; }
        default: cout << "wrong input";
        }
    }
}
```

case 1 works fine if i press 1 and default case works perfect as well.
the sentinel loop works fine too.
however when i press 2 it switches me to default.
what is wrong?
im new to c++ but this problem never happend.

Comment: You don't ever revaluate `c` so you will be stuck in 1 case forever. This might not be your problem but have you tried 2 right off the bat?

Comment: 'main' must return 'int'

Comment: `case 2` does *nothing*.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [Here](http://ideone.com/LlQl2U) it enters case 2 just fine. It does nothing after that. Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine (except that main must return an `int`):

[Live example](http://ideone.com/LlQl2U)

It might just be that your case 2 is not doing what you think it does. 
Because of this line:

```
while (counter2 >= counter)
```

and the fact that `counter2 == 1` and `counter == 30` your while loop will never be entered and `case (2)` will print nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you have a never ending loop please check this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c=0, sum = 0, y;
    cout << "press (1) to find the sum of 2 even numbers between 2 integers or press (2) to find all the prime numbers between 10 and 30,or press -1 to terminate";
    cin >> c;
    while (c != 1)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case (1) :
        {int x=0;
            cout << "enter 2 integers\n";
            cin >> x >> y;
            while (x<= y)
            {
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    sum = sum +x;
                x++;
            }
            cout << "sum is" << sum;
            break;
        }
        case(2) :
        {int counter = 30, counter2 = 1, nod = 0;
            while (counter >= 10)
            {
                cout << "hello im case 2";
                while (counter2 >= counter)
                {
                    if (counter%counter2 == 0)
                        nod = nod + 1;
                    counter2++;
                }
                if (nod == 2)
                    cout << counter << " is prime number";
                counter--;
            }
           } break; 
        default: cout << "wrong input";
        }
    }
}
```

check it here: 
http://cpp.sh/5ond

Comment: btw it will print hello im case 2 infinite times change your counter 2 values or modify your if clause

Answer (score -1):

```
do {
  cin >> c;
  switch {
    case (1): {
      // Your code
    }
    case (2): {
      // Your code
    }
    case (-1): {
      // Terminate
    }
    default: {
      // Your code
    }
  }
} while (true);
```